# Facebook / Meta Coding Puzzle -- Rotary Lock (Chapter 2)

Tags: python, facebook

[coding challenge screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYatx.png)

This is from Facebook/Meta Careers page practice problems
here is my current solution so far 2/32 test cases passed, has anyone been able to get 32/32?

```
from typing import List
# Write any import statements here

def getMinCodeEntryTime(N: int, M: int, C: List[int]) -> int:
  # Write your code here
  dial_1 = 1
  dial_2 = 1
  count = 0
  code = C
  
  if len(code) > 0:
    for number in code:
      print("before: dial_1, dial_2: ", dial_1, dial_2)

      fwd_1 = abs(number - dial_1)
      rev_1 = N - abs(number - dial_1)

      fwd_2 = abs(number - dial_2)
      rev_2 = N - abs(number - dial_2)

      # Dial 1 calc: fwd vs rev
      if fwd_1 > rev_1:
        count_1 = rev_1
      else:
        count_1 = fwd_1

      # Dial 2 calc: fwd vs rev
      if fwd_2 > rev_2:
        count_2 = rev_2
      else:
        count_2 = fwd_2

      # Dial 1 vs Dial 2 movement decision
      if count_1 > count_2:
        dial_2 = number
        count += count_2
      else:
        dial_1 = number
        count += count_1

      print("after: dial_1, dial_2: ", dial_1, dial_2, "+/-", count)
    
  return count
```

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is greedy.  You always move the closest deal to the next number.  Sometimes, you have to make a suboptimal move to get the best overall answer.  (There are times greedy algorithms are optimal, but not here.)

Try writing a recursive function:`best(n, other)` gives you the number of moves to solve steps numbers `Cn+1` to the end, assuming the two dials are at `Cn` and other.  This will be a nice recursive function.  Now rewrite the recursion in terms of dynamic programming.

Please don't expect anyone to write the code for you.